# Combinations in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

A

```
ID      ID_DESC1
1    123              
1    124
1    126
2    127
2    124
2    126
3    130
3    124
3    126
4    131 
4    124
4    126
```

B

```
ID_DESC1    DESC
123       ACTIVE
124       SAR
126       SAR1
127       REAL
130       TRI
131       ACC
```

Query should fetch the only ID's for Table A join B with the following combinations
Result Expected

```
Combination1: - ACTIVE,SAR,SAR1
Combination2: - REAL,SAR,SAR1
Combination3: - ACC,SAR,SAR1
```

Result shoiuld only fetch ID 1,2,4 and not 3

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Comment: Your question is severely lacking.  Here's stuff, I want this answer to not include 3.  What is the basis that EXCLUDES 3, or the basis that the others are included?  Is it because the others have both SAR and SAR1?  OR, will you always be providing certain "combinations" and want any ID that qualifies for an entire SET such that one ID contains all parts of the combination?  Please edit and update your question with clarification.  Don't try to post via a comment which is limited and just bloats the comment log.

Comment: Hi DRapp, I have already got my answer with LISTAGG function, question is perfect, i think you didn’t understand it quite correct. Please read question carefully

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The above query can be answered by LISTAGG with in oracle

Answer (score 2):

This is an example of a group-with-g

```
select a.id
from a join
     b
     on a.id_desc1 = b.id_desc1
group by a.id
having sum(case when b.desc = 'SAR' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when b.desc = 'SAR1' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 and
       sum(case when b.desc in ('ACTIVE', 'REAL', 'ACC') then 1 else 0 end) > 0;
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, the above query result says invalid relational operator

Comment: Using Oracle database